# One "IF" for all inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have many fieldset ids. And moving in form by button name for JavaScript. For example:

HTML

```
<fieldset id="firstField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Do yo have a fever?</h2>
        <input type="button" name="feveryes" class="next action-button" value="Yes" />
        <input type="button" name="feverno" class="next action-button" value="No" />
    </fieldset>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'feveryes')
        next_fs = $('#feveryes');
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'feverno')
        next_fs = $('#feverno');
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'coughyes')
        next_fs = $('#coughyes');
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'coughno')
        next_fs = $('#coughno');
```

Is it any way to make button "back" to move one step back on any level in form? For example:

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="prev" class="back action-button" value="Back" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(".back").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'prev')
        back_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
```

This code is probably wrong, but I try make one "if" for all buttons back.

Please, give me yours ideas.. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj8pd5op/59/)

Comment: just because you see a lot of if statements does not mean the code is wrong or the code will be clearer by removing them.  WHY change this code.  Seems fine to me.

Comment: you could consider dropping hidden input fields on each form that point to a next/previous form id, and then use those hidden field values to determine which form to show/hide

Comment: I try to make easier the work for not create any if for "step back" on any level.

Comment: The only problem I can imagine with this approach is that it's hard coded to the DOM, and should you add, or remove, sections you've got a lot of jQuery/JavaScript to rewrite; if you can show more of your HTML I imagine there's a far easier – and less verbose – approach to be taken instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your IDs always match the input's names, all your `if` statements can collapse to:

```
next_fs = $('#' + $(this).attr('name'));
```

You can use an array to keep track of the previously viewed fieldset.

```
var progress = [];
```

Before showing the next screen, push the current screen into the array:

```
progress.push($('fieldset:visible'));
```

When you click the Back button, `pop()` the last fieldset from the array and display it:

```
back_fs = progress.pop();
back_fs.show();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x183c2t/1/)**

Comment: Please try: "Do you have a fever" -> No -> "You are healthy!" -> back - and we have no "back" only "Go to Doctor". Why?

Comment: It's because "Go to Doctor" is the previous fieldset to "You are healthy."  You'll need to keep track of the previously *viewed* fieldset with a variable or `data-` field.

Comment: See my edit, which uses an array to keep track of the progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `data-` tag for your "next" action on each `<input>` element:

```
<input type="button" name="feveryes" class="next action-button" data-next-fs="#feveryes" value="Yes" />
```

And then look it up in the click handler:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $($(this).data('next-fs'));
});
```

This gives you a little more freedom over what the element names/IDs are.